# What is the lldb equivalent of gdb's rwatch?

Tags: gdb, lldb, watchpoint

I'm in a situation where read watchpoints would be very handy. Looking at lldb's help, I could find the `watchpoint` command, but it only seems to support write watchpoints (which are admittedly a lot more useful in general, but won't do it in my case).

I know that gdb has a `rwatch` command that sets read watchpoints. Is there any equivalent with lldb?

Comment: As a side note, I'll obviously just use gdb to get my stuff done for this time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`watch set variable|expression` both take a `-w` / `--watch` argument specifying either `write` (default), `read`, or `read_write`.  e.g.

```
(lldb) wa s v -w read myvar
```

Comment: Oh, I see. I guess I didn't dig deep enough into the help.